# Need help on MongoDB query Activity (1...n) Subscription (1...n) Invoice

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB database with following Model relationship.
'Activity' has many 'Subscriptions'. 'Subscriptions' have many 'Invoices'.
Each subscription belongs to one activity. Each invoice belong to one subscription

Given an Activity I want to find out COUNT of all invoices related with this 'Activity'

How such query can be written in MongoDB?
(I want to avoid adding reference of activity in each invoice)

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand you, you have 3 collections: Activity, Subscriptions which have links to Activity and Invoices wich have links to Subscriptions. If so, your code should look like this

```
db.invoices.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'subscriptions',
      localField: 'subscriptionId',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'subscription'
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'activities',
      localField: 'subscription.activityId',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'activity'
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      'activity._id': 'your activity _id'
    }
  },
  {
    $count: 'invoice_count'
  }
])
```